# Does experience gain from damaging Restoration Spells depend on damage dealt?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

Dawnguard introduces a few restoration spells which do sun damage.

Consider the following: according to [the UESP wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Restoration#Spells), *Vampire's Bane* grants 36 XP:
*Vampire's Bane* is described as such:

> Sunlight explosion that does 40 points of damage in a 15 foot radius to undead

However, this spell can do up to 50 damage with the *Necromage* perk, and 500 damage if it hits 10 enemies. It can also deal only 10 damage, if one is playing on the legendary difficulty. Does damage dealt affect experience gain?

Are there any exceptions?

One exception is *Stendarr's Aura*, which, due to a bug, grants destruction XP instead. What about the other spells?

Comment: http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Stendarr%27s_Aura

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. It helps though.

Comment: I voted to reopen. This seems like a perfectly reasonable question that is sufficiently narrow in scope: "Do restoration spells that do damage give you experience based on the amount of damage?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on what I can find in the [Skyrim:Leveling - Skill XP](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Leveling#Skill_XP) UESP wiki article,
it doesn't seem like spell damage matters.

> Restoration skill - sources of XP/Notes:
>
> - 1 base XP damage healed by healing spells.
> - 1 base XP per Magicka used on non-healing spells.
> - Additional multipliers may apply.

Although this might be slightly dated. Bane of the Undead also deals damage, but indirectly and is in the base game.

Through this, I am fairly certain that damage doesn't matter for Restoration.